# Why `Chop` does not make the real part of machine complex numbers an exact zero?

Tags: functions, complex

The documentation says

> Chop does not make the real part of machine complex numbers an exact
>   zero:
>
> In[2]:= Chop[10.^-12 + 2. I]
>
> Out[2]= 0. + 2. I

Why does `Chop` leaves such a useless 0.?

Comment: Ponder on the result of `Complex[0, 2.]`.

Comment: @Artes Thanks for the link

Comment: You can also use `Rationalize` to convert to an exact number.

Comment: @BobHanlon Good suggestions, thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Complex numbers are atomic in Mathematica.  Their real and imaginary parts cannot be separated.  Thus both must have the same type: either floating point (inexact) or exact number.

`1.` is an inexact `Real`, not `Complex`. It has no imaginary part. Thus `Im[1.]` can give `0`.

But `2. I` is an inexact `Complex`, which *does have* a real part even if it's zero. Since this is an exact type, its real part is an inexact zero.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and I am reading your comment on my Mingw problem right now :)